Allow entering numbers and decimals only - no text, special characters nor datetime in excel cells using data validation
I am trying to force the user to only enter numbers/decimal numbers to cells in excel using data validation custom formula. I tried a range of ways such as using =ISNUMBER(cellID)and =AND(ISNUMBER(A1), A1=TEXT(A1,"General")).
The issue is that I eiter can't enter decimals or it allows time to enter which changes the  cell format to custom.
What I want is to only allow number and decimal. But seems to be impossible.
Let me know if any one has suggestions.

May I ask why the built-in data validation for decimal with from/to range is not helpful for your case?

@nkalvi Presumably, because the built-in data validation will accept Date/Time values (because Dates and Times are just Numbers with special formatting applied)

Thank you @Chronocidal, now I understand why it wasn't chosen.

To check if a value is numeric, simply check whether or not negating it gives an error.  However, Dates and Times are numeric, they just happen to be Numbers with special Formatting applied.  (This being why the built-in "Decimal" validation will permit both Dates and Times to be typed in.)
You can use the CELL function to retrieve information about the Cell's formatting: =CELL("format"[, A1])
For the "Integer and Decimal" portions, we want results similar to these:



Formatting
=CEll("format")




General
"G"


0
"F0"


#,##0
",0"


0.00
"F2"


#,##0.00
",2"



So, we can just check if the returned Format Code starts with "G", "F", or ",":
=IFERROR(FIND(LEFT(CELL("format", A1), 1), "FG,"), 0)>0

(Add "P" to permit Percentages, "C" for Currency, or "S" for Scientific Notation)
Then we combine the two:
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(-A1)), IFERROR(FIND(LEFT(CELL("format", A1), 1),"FG,"), 0)>0)


@nkalvi If you have the format set (e.g. to "F0" or ",2") then it forces the format to remain, yes.  However, if it's set to "G" (i.e. "General"/default) then typing in a Date or a Time attempts to change the cell format, and this will cause the Validation to fail.  (At least, in App version of Excel; not sure about the Web version, which sometimes runs calculations and events in a different order)
But, if you have already explicitly specified a format, then you won't get the "dates and times cause the format to change" issue that OP was worried about anyway.
